# yes or no loop (TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable) error

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement a yes / no / retry, but I am getting this error:  'NoneType' object is not iterable. I assume the issue is the function (def izberiEkipo() is not returning what it's suppose to.

```
def izberiEkipo():

    m  = set(['m'])
    p = set(['p'])


    while False:
        if reply in m:
            with open('vprasanja2.txt') as f:
                vsaVprasanja = [line.strip() for line in f]
                max_line = len(vsaVprasanja)
            True


        elif reply in p:
            with open('vprasanja.txt') as f:
                vsaVprasanja = [line.strip() for line in f]
                max_line = len(vsaVprasanja)
            True

        else:

            sys.stdout.write("Answer with 'm' ord 'p'")


        return (max_line, vsaVprasanja)  

def genVprasanja ():

    obsVred = set()
    maxL, vsaQ = izberiEkipo()
    tocke = 5
    total = 0
       .
       .
     [...]
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. Your code is basically unreadable at this point.

Comment: Please make the code sample a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), with the smallest amount of code others can copy/paste to get the same error. Right now, because it requires external text files (and has pseudocode contents), nobody else can run it -- and there's also a fair bit of content that has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Comment: `while False` shouldn't run. Default is `True`. You need to provide a traceback. It's either `while True` or `while not my_variable_check`

Comment: @roganjosh. `while False:` doesn't run, and since the `return` is in the loop, the function returns `None`, which then gets unpacked into `maxL, vsaQ`, causing the error.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct: as given, your upper function returns nothing.  You've disabled the loop with a **False** entry condition: it won't run at all.  The only **return** in the function is inside that loop.

Thus, all that routine does is to create two sets of a single character each, and then return **None** to the main program.  Since you haven't included code to reproduce the problem -- in fact, the line that throws the error isn't in your example -- and no trace-back, we can't help much farther than this.